# Can I convert Object key return value to a non-string value? REACT proplem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the data in object using setState 'react' method. But instead of writing function for each key in the state object, I tried create one object and return key from that object. e.g. I am using class method for creating components

```
state = {
 value1: 'value place', 
 value2: 'value 2 placed',
}
handleChange = (e) => {
 this.setState({
// here i am putting the setstate keyname from the element. This returns string for which 
// this won't work. 
 this.props.keyname = e.target.value,
})
}
render(){
 return (<div>
 <h1>{this.state.value1}</h1>
 <input type="text" value={this.state.value1}  onChange={this.handleChange} keyname={Object.keys(this.state)[0]}/>
</div>)
}
```

As seen above I want to pass on the keyname of that state and get it in the setState using props. But because the returned value is a string, this solution won't work.
Is there anyways of getting this string work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mutate the props, which is impossible. If you want to use the key as a state key:

```
this.setState({
 [this.props.keyname]: e.target.value,
})
```